# date picker in ios application

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, datepicker, uitextfield

i am new to iPhone development. I want to add a `UIDatePicker` when textfield is selected.
two date picker is there.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)aTextField
{

    [aTextField resignFirstResponder];

    pickerViewPopup = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

    UIDatePicker *pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 0, 0)];
    pickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    pickerView.hidden = NO;
    pickerView.date = [NSDate date];

    UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    [pickerToolbar sizeToFit];

    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];

    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:)];
    [barItems addObject:doneBtn];

    UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelButtonPressed:)];
    [barItems addObject:cancelBtn];

    [pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];

    [pickerViewPopup addSubview:pickerToolbar];
    [pickerViewPopup addSubview:pickerView];
    [pickerViewPopup showInView:self.view];
    [pickerViewPopup setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 464)];
}
```

I used this but got same value for the two different datepickers. I want that if I press textfield1 then datepicker opens and saves that value in textfield one and same for the second textfield . Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Maulik:
First thing `- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)aTextField` is called every time the textfield is selected for editing.

So for both your selection i.e. textfield1 and textfield2 same code is going to be called.

What you can do is at the tap of done button, Check which textfield has opened up the picker and save the value in that textfield.

What I meant is take a textfield in .h file
`UITextField *selectedTextField;`

Then in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` method set it as `selectedTextField = aTextField;`
and at the tap of  done button i.e in `doneButtonPressed` set the selected value for `selectedTextField.text`. And thats it.. you are done :)

Comment: thank you for answer but i still can't do it.. please check this code -(void)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    //Do something here here with the value selected using [pickerView date] to get that value
    
    [pickerViewPopup dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:YES];
        
    
}

-(void)cancelButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [pickerViewPopup dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:YES];
}

Comment: @MaulikVekariya check out my answer in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624013/adding-a-button-to-uidatepicker/3624329#3624329

Comment: still i have no got ny output i got that when i touch on textfield1 then datepicker open this is best but when i select date and press done then print thi s value in textfield1 and textfield2 both i want both value sepretely..plz help me bhai...

Comment: buddy thats what I am saying in textFieldDidBeginEditing method add a code selectedTextField = aTextField; and at the place where you are assigning the value to textfield set the value in selectedTextField

Comment: @spverma : still i have prblm'

Comment: @MaulikVekariya Getting an upvote and Accepting the correct answer is the best way to thanks in SO

Answer (score 1):

I have an easy solution.

Set delegate `<UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource>`

In `.h` file:

```
UIDatePicker *dtPicker;
UIActionSheet *pickerViewPopup;

-(IBAction)dt_picker:(id)sender;
```

In `.m` file:

```
-(IBAction)dt_picker:(id)sender{

    pickerViewPopup = [[UIActionSheet alloc] init];
    const CGFloat toolbarHeight = 44.0f;
    dtPicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, toolbarHeight, 0, 0)];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter =[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    // if (dateStatus==0) {
        dtPicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
        dtPicker.minimumDate = [NSDate date];
    /* }else{
        datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];

    }*/
    dtPicker.hidden = NO;
    dtPicker.date = [NSDate date];

    [dtPicker addTarget:self action:@selector(LabelChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, toolbarHeight)];
    pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    [pickerToolbar sizeToFit];
    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    UIBarButtonItem *btnCancel = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(btncancelPressed:)];
    [barItems addObject:btnCancel];

    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];

    flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];

    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:)];
    [barItems addObject:doneBtn];


    lbl1.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dtPicker.date];


    [pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];

    [pickerViewPopup addSubview:pickerToolbar];
    [pickerViewPopup addSubview:dtPicker];
    [pickerViewPopup showInView:self.view.superview];
    [pickerViewPopup setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width, 464)];

}


-(void)LabelChange:(id)sender{

    NSDateFormatter* formatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
    [formatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

    NSString  *dateString= [formatter1 stringFromDate:dtPicker.date];
    lbl1.text=dateString;
}

-(void)btncancelPressed:(id)sender{
    [pickerViewPopup dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:YES];
}

-(void)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender{
    [pickerViewPopup dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:YES];
}
```